# PDO syntax whit querys

Tags: php, pdo

hi im starting to use PDO for sqlite and I want to know how to do something similar like:

```
$result = **sqlite_query**($conection,$consulta);
```

for example something similar to `$conection = sqlite_open('../db/traductor.db');`

would be--->`$conection = new PDO('sqlite:../db/traductor.db');`

hope you can understand my question, and thanks

Comment: Is this not answered in the PDO manual?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you've been pointed, the PHP PDO manual page will tell you where to look for, but I'll save you a couple of minutes.

In procedural MySQL, you would connect to your database with:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);
```

And fire your queries like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `product_id` ASC;", $link);
```

In PDO, it's a bit different:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8", "user", "password");
```

And you fire your queries (in a direct fashion) like this:

```
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `product_id` ASC;");
```

But the power of PDO lies within prepared statements

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `price` > ? ORDER BY `product_id` ASC;");
$statement->execute([27.75]);
```

Take your time and read the PDO manual page and as many tutorials on the web as you can. It's more difficult to work with PDO in the beginning but, once you learn, you won't want to work with anything less (not to mention you can link with MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MongoDB and many other databases using the same structure, among other advantages).

Hope that helped ;)

Comment: just curious, why you're calling execute in 3 lines instead of `execute([27.75])`?

Comment: True... forgot to make it simpler haha. I guess I'm 'too' accustomed to work with multiple elements, so I kind of hard-coded those two lines. Thanks for the pointer :P